# Can not load NSImageView image from file with NSImage(byReferencingFile: )

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsimage, nsimageview

When I want to set a image from my disc (*/Users/me/Desktop/image.png*) to the image of my `NSImageView` with `NSImage(byReferencingFile: )` it does not show it.

When I try `NSImage(named: )` with an image stored in the **assets-folder**, it works.

**The code within the viewController**

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: NSImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/Users/me/Desktop/image.png")
    }    
}
```

The *imageView* fills the entire window.

So I want to load the image stored on disk or at a specified URL.

Comment: Use `convenience init(byReferencing url: URL)` for URLs. Did you try with App Sandbox switched off?

Comment: Thanks, switching the App Sandbox off worked for me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke) helped me to find the solution. I had to switch `App Sandbox` in the **entitlements-file** from `YES` to `NO`

Answer (score 0):

To get to the UserDir you'll have to use:

```
let home = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
```

And from there you can add the path to the Image
Here is a tutorial on using the File System
https://www.raywenderlich.com/666-filemanager-class-tutorial-for-macos-getting-started-with-the-file-system

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

You can't add image from desktop to UIimageView, you only can add image (dragging) into project folders and then select the name image into UIimageView properties (inspector).

Comment: I am working on a Mac Application.

"The NSImage class serves many purposes, providing support for the following tasks:
- Loading images stored on disk or at a specified URL."(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage)